# Create a Rect from 4 points

Tags: java, android

I have 4 points that specify a rotated rectangle, and I want to be able see if a point is contained in that rectangle. I know that Rect object has a contains() method, but is there a way that I can create a rect based on 4 point. From my understanding, Rect takes 2 points, but doesn't account for a rotated Rect.

Comment: The two points are top left and bottom right, so you don't need 4 points... Are you trying to draw a Rectangle, or just create some object?

Comment: I cant understand your problem. Please explain more details.

Comment: I want to be able to figure out if a point lies inside a rectangle that is defined by 4 coordinates (top left, top right, bottom left and bottom right)

Comment: What's the anchor point around which the rectangle is rotated? Really, this boils down to a matter of arithmetic. If you have the coords of a single corner, along with the width and height, all you have to do is account for the rotation arithmetically and do some simple addition/subtraction. Also, does the rotation "snap" to a grid (always 90 rotations) or would the rotation be more irregular?

Comment: After you rotated a rectangle you try to use [Rect.sort()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#sort()) method to swap top/bottom or left/right(please have a read the document). And then, using the `Rect.contains()` to check whether a point is  contained in the rectangle